# Setting pre-commit-hook server side

Tags: git, server-side, pre-commit-hook

Is it possible to set up pre-commit-hooks in the server repo and have them download to the clients when the repo is cloned?

Comment: You can set up a `pre-receive` server-side hook, an `update` server-side hook and an `post-receive` server-side hook. For more Information read https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
What did you mean with "download to the clients when the repo is cloned"?

Comment: @Philj0 I take it to mean "I want to programmatically enforce that all clones of my repository use this set of pre-commit hooks."

Comment: I guess the feature of server-side hooks is, that you don't have to share it to everybody who cloned your repository :D But if you have to do it, look at the answer from @msanford

Comment: @Philj0 Yes I agree. I _think_ there is simply a conflation of terminology, thinking of a git "server" providing hooks, so it's a server-side hook. But I could be mistaken.

Comment: What I mean is that as a team, we would like are hooks to live with the repo on the server, in this case we are looking to distribute the pre-commit-hook, which basically formats the code and let's you know if it was successful. We want to avoid conflicts because of formatting issues, eg. spaces vs tabs and such

Comment: So I guess the only way to share the hooks with others is the way @msanford showed you in this answer. To do a pre-commit on server-side is not possible.

Comment: @FranciscoRangel That's exactly what I thought. In that case, there is presently no alternative than my solution, which is actually fairly trivial to implement. Similarly, you can use my suggestion to, say, run your received code through `pep8` or `jshint` or whatever linter you like to ensure that code format is respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

> The hooks are all stored in the `hooks` subdirectory of the Git directory. In most projects, that’s `.git/hooks`.

Recall that `.git/` is managed locally.

So, no, there is no programmatic way using only git to *force* a repository to install hooks when it is cloned.

That said, a common practice is to bundle hooks into a folder like `hooks/` within your repository, and then either

- explain how to install them in the README, or
- provide a script which will install them after cloning that the user has to run manually.

If you have rules you wish to validate, which you could use to smoke-test if someone has used a hook, you can install `pre-receive` hook in your remote.

For example, if you have a pre-commit hook that prepends a branch identifier to commit messages, you could check in a pre-recieve hook (actually on the 'server') that commit messages start with a branch identifier.