# Git hooks: where do I put them after I push to remote repo

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I've read the git hooks documentation and I'ms still trying to figure out where I put scripts for git hooks for certain events, and how I manage them:

Preconditions:

- Create bare git repository foo on some machine A
- Jenkins running on machine A
- I clone my repository foo to machine B
- I make some changes to foo on machine B
- Commit changes to foo on B
- Push changes to foo to A
- Assume master branch

Desired Behavior:
After pushing to machine A, I want Jenkins to kick off a build on machine A

One machine A, there is a hooks directory with various hook scripts samples.
One machine B, there is a .git/hooks directory with various hook script samples.

Questions:

- Where do I put the script to cause Jenkins to rebuild my app? On machine A or on machine B?
- What would the name be? post-push?
- If I put them on machine B, don't the scripts get wiped out if I delete my clone of foo and re-clone the repository?
- Would I have to re-create them if I re-clone?
- Are git hooks themselves version under git version control or do you just manage them free of source control?

Thanks

Comment: To closers: I argue that this question is not too broad: it does contain a specific scenario and a list of specific questions, it's just complex (and somewhat hypothetical?). It may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I put the script to cause Jenkins to rebuild my app?

On the machine that runs Jenkins (so on Machine A).

> What would the name be? post-push?

You want a `post-receive` hook (assuming A is your remote), [which](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks):

> [...] is run on the remote when pushing after the all refs have been
>   updated. It does not take parameters, but receives info through stdin
>   in the form of "  ". Because it is
>   called after the updates, it cannot abort the process.

-

> If I put them on machine B, don't the scripts get wiped out if I delete my clone of foo and re-clone the repository?
>
> Would I have to re-create them if I re-clone?

Yes. Because:

> Are git hooks themselves version under git version control or do you just manage them free of source control?

They are not because [active hooks live in `.git/hooks`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182740/setting-pre-commit-hook-server-side/47182903#47182903) which is not under version control. See that answer for more details.

That said, this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably don't want to do this specifically to trigger builds, but use Jenkins' polling to scan for changes, which would probably be simpler to manage.